# Structured reference lookup using the value of another cell

Tags: excel

The following works great:
`=LOOKUP(A9,People[Name],People[Age])`
Where A9 holds the name of the person I'm looking up.  This returns their age, no problem.

Here's what I want to do:
`=LOOKUP(A9,Items[Name],Items[D4])`
Where D4 holds the title of the column I am looking up in the table.  So if D4 held the word "Age" it would collect the person's age.

How do I go about doing that?
Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure LOOKUP is the best approach, even for your original formula. LOOKUP only works correctly if the Lookup range (People[Name] in this case) is sorted ascending....and even then you could get a false match - if A9 doesn't contain a name in the list the formula will return an age (in most cases), probably better to use INDEX/MATCH for an exact match, i.e. `=INDEX(People[Age],MATCH(A9,People[Name],0))`

Comment: Ok @barryhoudini, I can make that change... how do I implement the other half then?

Comment: My apologies, no answer appeared when I asked that question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Revised]

I think you'd need an INDEX/MATCH/MATCH formula if the column is variable, e.g. with a Table called `Items` try this formula

`=INDEX(Items,MATCH(A9,Items[Name],0),MATCH(D4,Items[#Headers],0))`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `INDIRECT()` to parse a string of text as a reference.

```
=LOOKUP(A9,Items[Name],INDIRECT("Items["&D4&"]"))
```